# Python 2.6 read from buffer

Tags: python, buffer, python-2.6, arcpy

In **Python 2.6**, how can I access a buffer? I'm using an external python class via arcpy to access a PostgreSQL database function.

```
# the_geom is part of a list.
print the_list
# Returns:... 'the_geom': <read-only buffer for 0x06E4FB60, size 1997, offset 0 at 0x34BCCB80>,...

for item in the_list:
    the_geom=item['the_geom']
    print(type(the_geom))
    # Returns: <type 'buffer'>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer`s can be sliced or iterated, just like other sequences.

```
>>> buffer('foobar')
<read-only buffer for 0x7fcdd7caa120, size -1, offset 0 at 0x7fcdd7ca82f0>
>>> buffer('foobar')[3:5]
'ba'
>>> for c in buffer('foobar'):
...   print c
... 
f
o
o
b
a
r
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been working on this for several issues and needed a sanity check to confirm that this part of my code was correct! Thanks again.